# How to append text to memo field?

Tags: sql, type-conversion, advantage-database-server

I'm using Advantage Database Server 9.10, and I want to append a text to Memo field.

I tried this way,

```
UPDATE 
  myTable 
SET 
  memo =   cast(memo as SQL_VARCHAR(max)) 
         + cast(' Appended string' as SQL_VARCHAR(max)) 
WHERE 
  pk = '80'
```

but it does not work,

anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Does not work = what. Invalid sql no change to data, memo doesn't end up with what you expected?

Comment: right that is invalid sql. and I want to this, supposing memo field(memo type) has 'ABC' value and I want to append to 'DEF' after 'ABC', how should I write query for this?

Comment: Don't know advantage myself, but some other boyz have weighed in. Can't say I like the idea. If I was using Text/Image/Blob, I'd be trying my hardest to only manipulate it client side. Encoding would cause some palpitations with this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `VARCHAR(MAX)` data type in ADS, but you can cast to `SQL_VARCHAR` or `SQL_CHAR` instead.

Correct syntax:

```
UPDATE
  myTable 
SET 
   memo =   cast(memo as SQL_VARCHAR) 
          + cast(' Appended string' as SQL_VARCHAR) 
WHERE 
   pk = '80'
```

You can find the valid list of data types for CAST and CONVERT in the ads documentation:

http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage10.1/master_miscellaneous_functions.htm

Answer (score 2):

I think you can write it more simply as:

```
UPDATE 
  myTable 
SET 
  memo = memo + ' Appended string' 
WHERE 
  pk = '80'
```

If the `memo` field might be NULL and you don't want the result to be NULL, you can do something like this:

```
...
SET
  memo = ifnull( memo, '' ) + ' Appended string'
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, you just have to make sure you allow for enough characters in the  `VARCHAR()`:

```
UPDATE 
   myTable 
SET 
   memo = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8000),memo) + ' Appended String'
FROM 
   myTable
WHERE 
   pk = '80'
```

I added the `FROM myTable` because in my project I had to `LEFT JOIN` a couple of tables also.